# Can't establish a relationship between NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have 1 ToDo object and I am creating 1 Report object. Both of them are NSManagedObject create of different MOC of the same NSManagedObjectContext. Just to make it clear, the NSManagedObjectContext is an ivar from my PersistenceStore class.

The ToDo object came from an array that inherit from a method in the PersistenceStore that returns arrays with objects saved in the NsPresistentStoreCoordinator. The todo object is passed as a attribute to the class where I should initialize a report.

The report class is initialized from a MOC of the PersistenceStorage NSManagedObject with this code lines:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [store managedObjectContext];
Report *report = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The Todo and Report objects have a relationship one - to - one. But one I try to set the relationship I got the error

> <\NSInvalidArgumentException> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'todo' between objects in different contexts

In my mind I using the same NSManagedObjectContext. Some can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find context of another entity:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [store managedObjectContext];

 NSManagedObject *ctx = [context existingObjectWithID:[todo objectID] error:&error];
Report *report = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

Comment: You maybe mean that `ctx` is a `NSManagedObjectContext`and not only `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: I fixed it. I use part of your solution:
The Report object also have other relationship, but with the original context, so if I have had use your solution I got problem with the other relationship. Then the solution was 

`NSManagedObjectContext *context = [store managedObjectContext];
 Report *report = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *object = [context objectRegisteredForID:[currentTodo objectID]];
        [report setTodo:((ToDo*) object)];
`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used part of the answer of NeverBe.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [store managedObjectContext]; 
Report *report = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
NSManagedObject *object = [context objectRegisteredForID:[currentTodo objectID]]; 
[report setTodo:((ToDo*) object)];
```

The reason I didn't used NeverBe answer is that Report object have other relationship in same context. If I copy the context of the Todo object I get the same problem with the rest of relationships.